# MPMoviePlayerController initWithContentURL check if the url contains a video

Tags: ios

I'm loading a video in MPMoviePlayerController from a URL, but when the URL passed is not a video, obviously it doesn't load into MPMoviePlayerController. The MPMoviePlayerController try and after many seconds trying it loads nil.

I need to know if there's anyway to check if the URL is a video?

There's my code:

```
NSString *videoURLStr = [listaVideos objectAtIndex:iCnt];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLStr];            
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
```